# Android - Database Class Structure OOP

Tags: android, oop, sqlite

I have been following a tutorial from a gentleman on YouTube called Prakeesh where he explains how to perform CRUD operations on a Database in Android.

So far I have the following code which works perfectly fine:

```
public class DataHandler {

public static final String NAME = "name";
public static final String TABLE_NAME = "mytable";
public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "mydatabase";
public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
public static final String TABLE_CREATE = "create table " + TABLE_NAME + " (" + NAME + " text not null);";
SQLiteDatabase database;

DatabaseHelper databaseHelper;
Context context;

public DataHandler(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
    databaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);
}

public DatabaseHelper open(){
    database = databaseHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    return databaseHelper;
}

public void close(){
    databaseHelper.close();
}

public long insert(String text){
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(NAME, text);
    return database.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues);
}

public Cursor returnData(){
    return database.query(TABLE_NAME, new String[] {NAME}, null, null, null, null, NAME);
}

// Database Helper Class
private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

    public DatabaseHelper(Context context){
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase) {
        sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(TABLE_CREATE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, int i, int i2) {
        sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);
        onCreate(sqLiteDatabase);
    }
}

}
```

In summary, the above contains a `DataHandler` class which contains the Database `Schema`, i.e. The Database name, my table name (just one table), the Database version etc. This class contains `CRUD` methods and a constructor which initialises the `DatabaseHelper` object.

The `DatabaseHelper` object is an inner class which extends SQLiteOpenHelper and overrides the `onCreate` and `onUpdate` methods which do exactly as they say.

My question, *finally*, is how do I re-organise and re-structure the above design so that I can perform `CRUD` operations on, say, a Restaurant Table or a User Table? Where would the DatabaseHelper sit? How would I reference the DatabaseHelper object within each object? How can I easily introduce many more objects which can have the same CRUD operations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd advise using a content provider with a contract, this then gives you a standard way of accessing your data and performing crud operations. Your database helper will then just do the setting up of the tables and populating any default data.

The contract defines the model objects, and then content provider can insert, update and delete these objects from the database from an abstracted layer above.

Content providers give you a lot as well, such as linking with loaders so you can have automatically refreshing list views based on it being bound to the content provider and "listening" for changes to the underlying data source.

Comment: Ahah. I was hoping I wouldn't be dragged in to content providers since they're extremely heavyweight (For me) and how on the Google documentation, it states that they are mainly used to access data from  an external prospective, i.e. outside the app. I guess i'll start looking in to it. Do you know of a good/easy to understand read for this approach please?

Comment: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_content_providers.htm - that seems pretty good. Also if you ever wanted to implement syncing via a sync adaptor, it'd require a content provider to access your data, so might not be a bad investment in time if that would ever apply to you.